# Get "name" for object, corresponding to package name and object name

Tags: scala, logging, slf4j

Given the object:

```
package com.foo.bar
object Sample {
   val LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(???)
   ....
}
```

what statement/function/whatever I put into **getLogger** statement in order to get "com.foo.bar.Sample" ?

Basically, it's just a matter of code style, for the moment I configured IntelliJ to generate LOG statements with strings, evaluated from template like "packagename.classname". But may be there's some better way?

Thanks.

Comment: You should try scala logging, it's simple, easy, and you don't have to guess class names or use logger factories: https://github.com/typesafehub/scalalogging

Comment: Yes, why would you want to put class names in source files when they are already there? DRY!

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could use `getClass().getName()`.

Comment: It doesn't work like this, it adds trailing $, and for nested objects the classname looks like opa.opa.opapa.test$test1$ instead of opa.opa.opapa.test.test1

Comment: So why don't you strip the trailing `$` and replace the other `$` by `.`?

Comment: in this case it's better to live with my current approach